# mails are not deleting from inbox

Tags: php, sql-server-2005

I try to delete mails from inbox and move it to trash folder but my code is not working. Can anyone suggest me something.

```
    if($attachment!="")
    {            
         /*  $outputList .='' . $send. '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;' .$subject.'&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;'.$time.'<hr/>';  */

        /* $outputList .='<table><tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="check"></td><td style="width:30%;text-align:left">' . $send. '</td><td style="width:42%; text-align:left">' .$subject. '</td><td style="width:3%">' . $attach . '</td><td style="width:30%">'.$time.'</td></tr></table>';  */

         $outputList .='<table><tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="check"></td><td style="width:30%;text-align:left">'.$sender.'</td><td style="width:45%;text-align:left">'.$subject.'</td><td style="width:3%" align="left" >' . $attach . '</td><td style="width:30%">'.$time.'</td></tr></table>';
        }
        else {
          $outputList .='<table><tr><td><input type="checkbox[]" value=" $row["topic_id"]" class="check"></td><td style="width:30%;text-align:left">'.$sender.'</td><td style="width:45%;text-align:left">' .$subject. '</td><td style="width:3%" align="left" ></td><td style="width:30%">'.$time.'</td></tr></table>';            
        }
    }


     <div class="delete">         
         <input name="del" type="button" value="delete" action=""/>
         <?php              
           include 'delete.php';

           if (isset($_POST['del']) && isset($_POST['check']))
       {               
             foreach($_POST['check'] as $del_id){
             $del_id = (int)$del_id;
             $result= odbc_exec($conn,"insert into trash (sender,cc,bcc,subject,message,attachment,filename,filesize,date) 
select sender,cc,bcc,subject,message,attachment,filename,filesize,date from inbox where ID=$del_id");

        if($result==true)
            {
              $result= odbc_exec($conn,"delete from sent where ID=$del_id"); 
               $move="message deleted";
            }else
              $move="cannot delect the mail";
            }
       }
     ?>         
     </div>
```

Comment: You should review your code, before posting

Answer (score 0):

According to the title you are trying to delete mails from your inbox, however in you code you post:

```
delete from sent where ID=$del_id
            ^^^^ sent != inbox
```

You should also add error handling, using for example `echo odbc_errormsg();` (just a simple example), to see what is happening with the database calls.